# Where do I need to apply the random.shuffle to get the cards to be random?

Tags: python

```
import random

suits = ["Diamonds", "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs"]
ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]

def create_deck():
    deck = set()
    for suit in suits:
        cards = {f"The {rank} of {suit}" for rank in ranks}
        deck.update(cards)
    return deck

def main():
    deck = create_deck()
    num_of_cards = int(input("How many cards would you like?: "))
    print("\n Here are your cards:")
    for _ in range(num_of_cards):
        print("", deck.pop())
    print(" There are", len(deck), "cards left in the deck.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried putting the random.shuffle in some of the places that make sense to me but it just ends up throwing errors. The code works as it should with the exception of the cards dealt are always the same and I want them to be random every time.

Comment: Why are you using a set?

Comment: you can't shuffle a set because they aren't ordered. You should put the cards in a list, then you can use `random.shuffle(deck)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either `shuffle` in `create_deck` before returning the deck, or in `main`after generating the deck.

I would tend to prefer shuffling in `main` as one could make the parallel to real life: getting a new (sorted) deck a cards, shuffling it, playing. From a practical point of view it doesn't make a difference.

Note that you need to use a **list** as container as sets are unordered :

```
import random
suits = ["Diamonds", "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs"]
ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]

def create_deck():
    deck = [f"The {rank} of {suit}" 
            for suit in suits
            for rank in ranks]
    return deck

def main():
    deck = create_deck()
    random.shuffle(deck)
    num_of_cards = int(input("How many cards would you like?: "))
    print("\n Here are your cards:")
    for _ in range(num_of_cards):
        print("", deck.pop())
    print(" There are", len(deck), "cards left in the deck.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example:

```
How many cards would you like?: 5
Here are your cards:
 The 9 of Clubs
 The 3 of Hearts
 The 10 of Hearts
 The 4 of Spades
 The Jack of Hearts
 There are 47 cards left in the deck.
```

Alternative: shuffling in `create_deck`

```
def create_deck():
    deck = [f"The {rank} of {suit}" 
            for suit in suits
            for rank in ranks]
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck
```

You could also make it an optional parameter:

```
def create_deck(shuffle=False):
    deck = [f"The {rank} of {suit}" 
            for suit in suits
            for rank in ranks]
    if shuffle:
        random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

# in main
deck = create_deck(shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Thank you mozway this has helped me greatly. I appreciate this and the detailed explanation of the how and why this works.

Comment: @Squirpel you're welcome, I added a few more options, I like the last one ;)

Answer (score -1):

I see an answer is posted, but post my own version here too:

I use a list instead of a set.

I comment the line where shuffle goes.

```py
import random

suits = ["Diamonds", "Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs"]
ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]

def create_deck():
    deck = []
    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            cards = f"The {rank} of {suit}"
            deck.append(cards)
    return deck

def main():
    deck = create_deck()
    random.shuffle(deck)   # <------  put it here.
    num_of_cards = int(input("How many cards would you like?: "))
    print("\n Here are your cards:")
    for i in range(num_of_cards):
        print(deck[i])
        deck.pop(i)
    print(" There are", len(deck), "cards left in the deck.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example of the output:

```
How many cards would you like?: 4

 Here are your cards:
The King of Hearts
The 8 of Diamonds
The Queen of Clubs
The 2 of Clubs
 There are 48 cards left in the deck.
```